# Completion of partial latin squares

Tags: combinatorics, latin-square, matrix-completion

I'm reading a PDF about completing partial latin squares. The reference is https://ajc.maths.uq.edu.au/pdf/22/ocr-ajc-v22-p247.pdf

There is a fact that doesn't have a proof here, and I can't find it:

> The back diagonal of a partial latin square $P$ of order $n$ is formed by the cells
>   ${(1, n), (2, n-1), ... , (n, 1)}.$ An entry $(x, y, s)$ of $P$, is said to lie on the back diagonal
>   of $P$ if $(x, y, s) \in P$ and $x + y = n + 1$, $(x, y, s)$ lies above the back diagonal
>   if $(x, y, s) \in P$ and $x + y < n + 1$, and $(x, y, s)$ lies below the back diagonal if
>   $(x, y, s) \in P$ and $x + y > n + 1$. Let $L$ be a latin square of order $n$, then $L$ can be
>   used to construct a new partial latin square $P( L)$ as follows:

- If $(x, y, s)$ lies on or above the back diagonal in $L$, then $(x, y, s) \in P(L)$.
- For all $i = 1, ... , n + 1, (i, n + 2 - i, n + 1) \in P (L ) $.

> Let $L$ be any latin square, of order $n$. The partial latin square $P(L)$, of order
>   $n + 1$ (as defined above), can always be completed.

Can anyone help me with the proof?

Comment: I believe the pdf you cite has a typo. The second bullet should read "For all $i=1,\dots,n+1,(i,\color{red}{n+2}-i,n+1)\in P(L)$." In the original wording, when $i=n+1$, the triple would be $(n+1,0,n+1)$, but the indices in that paper start from $1$.

Comment: Your pdf cites _Latin Squares: New Developments in the Theory and Applications_ edited by J. Denes and A.D. Keedwell, for a good proof of this lemma. The proof is quite tricky (understandably, as it is a piece of solving a 20 year conjecture). If you try hard enough, you can find it for free online...

Comment: @Mike Earnest I think i've tried hard enough... I can't find it :(

Comment: @MikeEarnest I've fixed the typo.

Comment: I found a copy at https://b-ok.cc/book/763505/92fa69

Comment: @zeta thanks a lot.